# Trigger "reset" backbone event on collection's empty result set

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have a Backbone collection which I am fetching and rendering the following way:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize : function(options){
     var self = this;
     this.template =  _.template(Index);
     this.collection = new WineCollection();
     this.collection.url = ApiConfig.winetards.getWineList;
     this.collection.on("reset", function(){self.render()});
     return this;
}
```

At somepoint the wineList collection will be empty. How can I trigger "reset" and then call render on when the result set is empty?

Comment: After which action it will be empty? You getting empty response after fetch, or just removing all models?

Comment: *"At somepoint"* is a vague problem description...

Comment: @VahanVardanyan, I will get an empty response on fetch.

Comment: @TJ, "At somepoint" is a scenario

Comment: @Ashwinkumar ok, then it is a vague "scenario". Can you explain it..?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options - write the logic in View or the Collection. If other parts of your application will care when the collection is empty, do it in the Collection. Otherwise it probably belongs in the View.

Unless you edit the Collection's `models` Array directly, the Collection can only *become* empty after a `reset` or `remove` event. You can listen to these events and check for an empty Collection.

## In the view

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

  initialize : function(options){
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'remove reset', this.renderIfEmpty, this);
  },

  renderIfEmpty: function() {
    if(this.collection.isEmpty()) {
      this.render();
    }
  }
}
```

## In the collection

```
var WineList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.on('remove reset', this.checkEmpty);

    // If you want to trigger an event when an empty collection is created:
    this.checkEmpty();
  },

  checkEmpty: function() {
    if(this.isEmpty()) {
      this.trigger('emptied', this)
    }
  }
})
```